# How is Ubiquiti off topic?

Tags: discussion

As a long time SE user, but newcomer to networkengineering there seems to be some animosity towards Ubiquiti here -- mainly from not offering enterprise support.

However Ubiquiti should be on topic for these reasons:

- It meets the paid enterprise-support criteria in [help/on-topic](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), see [unifi cloud support](https://ui.com/site-support), their [enterprise helpdesk](https://help.ui.com/hc/en-us/articles/18116271784215-UniFi-Identity-Enterprise-Helpdesk), their [chat support with Tier 1 engineers](https://help.ui.com/hc/en-us/articles/12257617810327-Ubiquiti-Support-and-User-Responsibilities), and their [free forum, where employees respond](https://community.ui.com/).
- There are [hundreds of upvoted Ubiquiti posts](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=ubiquiti&searchOn=3) which haven't been moved off-topic.
- There is a `ubiquiti` tag [in tags](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/tags)
- They offer enterprise hardware, servicing large enterprise deployments such as college campuses (e.g. Berkeley) and fortune 500 companies (e.g. GM, Lockheed).

If kept off-topic, perhaps some clarification / cleanup is needed.

Answer (score 0):

First, that support is new, but it is limited, not covering the product lines often asked about here:

> What systems can Site Support help with?
>
> UniFi Site Support provides priority phone support to a single
> physical site managed with a UniFi Cloud Gateway. Site Support will be
> available for other types of UniFi site deployments in the future.

It is site support for cloud systems, not individual support to buy for a router.

The legacy questions prior to the decisions on topic requirements are typically left alone unless someone objects to a specific question (it would be much work to got through all the old questions to remove what is now off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

It should also be noted, many of the questions you point out with that search are not entirely about the UBNT hardware and/or software. Are there any *specific* closed questions you think shouldn't be?

As with everything, the devil is in the details... what is being asked, what specific bits of hardware are involved (usually more than just a single UBNT device), how is it being used, and *where* is it being used.